# return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0] UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 263:

Tags: python, return, byte

```
path = r"D:\Python_Course_with_Notes[1]\9. Chapter 9\ok.txt"
path2 = r"D:\Python_Course_with_Notes[1]\9. Chapter 9\this.txt"

with open(path) as f:
    check = f.read()

with open(path2) as f:
    to_check = f.read()

if check == to_check:
    print("Yes this file matches with another file")
else:
    print("No this file doesn't matches with another file")
```

Error:
return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 263: character maps to

Comment: You have providen your code and the error message, which is nice. But you could have given some context and said which line raises the error message. That being said the error is a hint that at least one of your files uses a charset different from the default of your Python installation. You have to declare the encoding in the `open` call.

Comment: How can I find which line raises the error message?